# Set Github action env variable based on target branch

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to set different env variables according to the target branch of the pull request.

For example, I am trying to have separate env variable for main and develop, but the ci is keeping such step and not running the actions

```
      - name: Make envfile for develop
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop'}}
        with:
      - name: Make envfile for main
        uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'}}
        with:
```

Comment: Please state what your expectations were and what actually happened. Also, please share logs.

Comment: There are no logs since the actions don't run. It is ignoring the if statements and the code inside them does not get to execute. The expectation is basically to run the code after `with`, but my guess is that it is ignoring the `github.ref` condition

Comment: Please [enable debug logging](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging) and share the logs from that.